# How to access shape of new features selected in sklearn custom transformer for different hyperparamters

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, keras

I am using custom defined transformer for important features selection via following code

```
class fs(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

def __init__(self, n_estimators=10):
    self.ss=None
    self.n_estimators = n_estimators
    self.x_new = None


def fit(self, X, y):
    m = ExtraTreesClassifier(10)
    m.fit(X,y)
    self.ss = SelectFromModel(m, prefit=True)
    return self

def transform(self, X):
    self.x_new=self.ss.transform(X)
    return self.x_new`
```

Here `x_new` are the new features selected by my custom transformer `fs`.

Then I am defining my Neural Network as a classifier in my pipeline as follows.

```
def create_model(dropout_rate=0.1):

my_model=fs()
x_new=my_model.x_new
n_x_new=x_new.shape[1]
np.random.seed(6000)
model_new = Sequential()
model_new.add(Dense(n_x_new,input_dim=n_x_new ,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
...............................rest of the code................................
```

Using sklearn Pipeline with the following code.

```
clf=KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=1000, verbose=0)

model = Pipeline([('fs', fs()),('clf', clf)])

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model,param_grid={"clf__dropout_rate": [0.1, 0.2]},scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=1)
grid_result = grid.fit(train_cv_x, train_cv_y)
```

I am getting the following error. How will my Keras model know about the shape of `x_new` selected for every hyperparamter.

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: Because the fs inside the `create_model` is not fitted yet. So the `self.x_new` is still None. The fs() defined in the pipeline is different. And this is not what I meant when I said to wrap the kerasClassifier into a custom estimator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem without making a custom estimate wrapper for my keras model with a very simple trick.  When I looked at the error I was getting, It was something like this.

I just hard coded the `input_dim` value to check if those selected important features are passed to my keras model or not.

```
model_new.add(Dense(n_x_new,input_dim=200 ,kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
```

> expected dense_22_input to have shape (None, 200) but got array with shape (10328, 428)

The error says that my keras model is actually getting the selecting important features from `fs()` but as I have defined the `input_dim=200`and this is not matching with the feature seize it gets from `fs()`.

The only issue was to somehow know about the number of features selected for every hyperparameter and then give that number to `input_dim` of the keras model.

I declared a global variable and saved the `self.x_new` value in my `fs()` in that global variable.

That global variable is accessible in keras model.

There might be some other more robust solutions like, making custom wrapper for keras classifier.